# How to build a barchart showing dependencies between two variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to create the following barchart. On X axis I want to show the values of `train['temp]`, while on Y axis - `train['icecream_demand']`. Please notice that `train['temp']` has continuous values, while `train['icecream_demand']` has discrete values.

I don't want to build a scatter plot. The idea is to show the typical icecream demand for different ranges of temperature.

I don't provide sample data, because I'm just searching for some example of how to build identical plot.

Update:
For illustration purposes I still want to provide some data from `train`.

```
             datetime  season  holiday  workingday  weather  temp   atemp  \
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00       1        0           0        1  9.84  14.395   
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00       1        0           0        1  9.02  13.635   
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00       1        0           0        1  9.02  13.635   
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00       1        0           0        1  9.84  14.395   
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00       1        0           0        1  9.84  14.395   

   humidity  windspeed  icecream_demand 
0        81          0  16  
1        80          0  40  
2        80          0  32  
3        75          0  13  
4        75          0  1
```

Comment: So does icecream demand map to particular ranges in temperature in your data? If so, can't you just bin your temperatures accordingly and then plot your bar chart?

Comment: @areuexperienced: Please check my update. Could you give some example illustrating your idea? (with a 'dummy' data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you want what Seaborn calls a "[stripplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html)".  Here's a super-simplified example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

ic

    icecream_demand temp
0   16  9.84
1   40  9.02
2   32  9.02
3   13  9.84
4   1   9.84

ic.dtypes  #to show that this can work with categorical data

icecream_demand     object
temp               float64
dtype: object

sb.stripplot(x="temp", y="icecream_demand", data=ic);
```

[image]

Here's another example image that might help clarify what's different about stripplots and scatterplots:

[image]